# HTML post form not worked when migrated to Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am doing a POST request using an HTML form, I copied the same form content to a new blank Angular project and it didn't work and throws an error. Does Angular process forms in a different way?

Actually, what the HTML/JS file is doing is to post form content to a URL (by sending a unique generated hash and some other information), upon success it will redirect to the correct page, otherwise, it will throw an error.

Unfortunately, the backend doesn't support sending a JSON request to it, but only a form.

The code snippet for the HTML form:

```
<form name="formpaiement" Id="formpaiement" action="https://testpayment.cmi.co.ma/fim/est3Dgate" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hashAlgorithm" value="ver3">
    <input type="hidden" name="encoding" value="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="TranType" value="PreAuth">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="504">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="CallbackResponse" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="BillToCountry" value="MA">
    <input type="hidden" name="storetype" value="3D_PAY_HOSTING">
    <input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="https://testpayment.cmi.co.ma/fim/est3dteststoreutf8?pagelang=en">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="80000xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="okUrl" value="http://cmiecom.dx.am/ok.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">

    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTSAFE" value="MERCHANTSAFE" />
    Token : <input type="Text" name="MERCHANTSAFEKEY" value="ABC123">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTSAFEAUTHTYPE" value="3DPAYAUTH">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTSAFEACQUIRER" value="60">
    <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTGROUPID" value="60029">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="hash">
</form>

<input type="submit" value="valider" onclick="document.formpaiement.submit()">
```

[Link to the working HTML file](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-r2bz33)

[Link to the Angular project](http://plnkr.co/edit/wxNg0nOFj9Nzl9vs) (you may notice that's not the best way to submit form content, but, just for demo purposes, it will look similar to the above HTML file).

Comment: What backend is it that wouldn't accept JSON?

Comment: what error does it throw? And yes Angular does some stuff with forms, it sounds like you haven't worked with Angular. I suggest doing the heroes tour as an intro to Angular (https://angular.io/tutorial), good luck

Comment: @LarsVanderheydt I have been working with Angular +7 years, please check the second link to view the error

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I don't know, but it's a local payment processor (something like stripe)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is how you've defined the `hash` field in you form. In the plunker that generates the error, you're sending `undefined` as the value for the `hash` field. In the stackblitz example that works there's an actual value.

Here's what your form data looks like in the plunker:
[image: Form Data (missing value for "hash")]

And here's what the stackblitz sends:
[image]

In your working example, you have an `onclick` event that appears to compute the value for "hash", append it to the form and then submit it. Snippet taken from the stackblitz:

```
function submitformpaiement() {
    hashval = "";
    // compute value for "hashval" (removed for brevity)


    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "hash").attr('value', hash).appendTo('#formpaiement');


    document.formpaiement.submit();
  }

<input type="submit" value="valider" onclick="submitformpaiement();">
```

In your Angular version, you've  added the `hash` field and bound the value to something that doesn't exist (hence `undefined`). Your `onclick` event also doesn't execute any function, it just submits the form.

```
<form name="formpaiement" Id="formpaiement" action="https://testpayment.cmi.co.ma/fim/est3Dgate"  method="post">

  <!--lots of inputs (removed for brevity) -->


  <!-- "hashCMI" doesn't exist!! -->
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" [value]="hashCMI">    

</form>
```

I suspect you need to make sure you generate a value for `hash` before actually submitting.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you didn't see it, there is actually a variable called `hashCMI` inside app.ts `hashCMI = cmi.submitformpaiement();` and indeed the `hash` is already generated even before clicking the submit button.

Comment: You're right, the variable is there now. Either I missed it when I originally wrote my answer or the plunker was updated to include it. I suspect the latter because the inclusion of that line appears to have broken the app (lots of console errors). In fact, removing that line allows the app to run and reproduce the original problem.

Comment: In any case, I think there's enough information in my answer and others for OP to find and fix the problem. OP needs to ensure that the angular version of the app is correctly setting the form values.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a very specific way of working with forms (https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview), and a very specific way of working with web services (https://angular.io/guide/http). Unfortunately, just having the form in the template is not going to work - you might as well not use Angular at all if that's your intention.

But that is not the only problem.

Looking at your two examples, what you have on Stackblitz describing as the "HTML example" vs. on Plunkr with Angular are not doing the same thing, so you can't compare one to the other.

In your Stackblitz example, there is a whole bunch of javascript that's executed prior to the form being submitted. If I change your example to do the same thing that your Angular example is doing, you get the same exact result as the Angular error. Here's the comparable "just HTML" example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-2gvw46

So the solution is to make sure your Angular application is doing the same exact logic as your original Stackblitz example, and does it in an Angular way (you can't copy/paste the JavaScript from the other example and expect it to work).